# GCM Cordova Push Notification not working when App not running

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

The application is in PhoneGap. I am using push notification feature with https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

I implemented the whole feature and it worked fine until yesterday. When I checked the app last day, push notification is not working when the app is not running. All notifications are receiving on my device, clicking on the message opens the app.

But the controls are not receiving at the javascript portion where message notification handles.

Code from file GCMIntentService.java:

```
JSONObject json;
json = new JSONObject().put("event", "message");

json.put("message", extras.getString("message"));
json.put("link", extras.getString("link"));

Log.v(ME + ":onMessage ", json.toString());

GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json );
// Send the MESSAGE to the Javascript application
```

This code will work when the message received. But at that time, App is not running.

When I click on the notification message, the app opens as usual, not registering the message event; thereby not getting the control in JavaScript to handle push notification.

Code for CORDOVA_GCM_script.js is available at:

> https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova/blob/master/assets/www/CORDOVA_GCM_script.js

**Note**: It works fine when the app is running.

***EDIT:***
The notification runs sometimes. JavaScript is getting message event randomly.

**EDIT 2:**

I definitely know the problem.

From the java file, it triggers the javascript code when opening the app by clicking on the push notification message. But at that time, the WebView is not loaded, so not able to execute the script (which is an event trigger). Is this is the condition, everyone using the plugin will experience the same. Is there any workaround or any fix for it?

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The point of push notification is that it runs in the background when your app is not running. Hence, if your app is not running and in this case, it being a WebView, I don't think it will receive anything from the native side since the JVM doesn't run the WebView in background which explains why your JS portion doesn't run when the app is not running. You must consider storing the notification data in shared preferences or something when you receive the push notification; examine that each time your app is launched so you can react to it.

Comment: This is a common implementation and I didn't find any issues reported by other, which confusing me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GCM-Cordova plugin will not handle the notification correctly if the application is not running. It is because the WebView was not loaded at the time when the plugin initiate the javascript.

**Solution:**

- Modified the plugin code to save message data as temporary when the notice arrives.
- Created another plugin with methods to read this loaded data and clear data.
- Call my custom plugin method on deviceready and checked if there any data.
- If there any, clear the locally stored data and invoke the method to show notice message.

Finally able to solve this issue with the help of two plugins - GCM-Cordova and custom plugin.

Comment: This would not solve the problem for me because the data I send in the message is used to set alarms on the phone and the user may not re-visit the app.

Comment: If you are creating a custom plugin, then that will run in the time when notification arrives (or user clicks to the notice). You can set the alarm code within the custom plugin code.

I would like to share my code, but I am working for an IT company and the code is strictly protected.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a lot of code sitting inside the javascript callback function now and it would be a substantial job rewriting everything and I simply don't have time. My solution, and this is less than ideal, is to launch the app if it isn't running when a push message is received then wait five seconds for it to load and then process the push. Works but obviously the user isn't going to be too impressed that their app is launching without them triggering it.

Comment: I tried this approach also. But for my specific requirement, this type of approach wont work.

Answer (score 3):

IvenMS - I too am having the same problem so you are not the only one.  If I understand praneetloke correctly, the Push Notifications will not work with PhoneGap apps which are not currently running.

Comment: There is nothing like not running the app. The app will run in background all the time, or its instances will run. When the messages pushes from server, the application will get control and register message in JavaCode. I can see the logging with JavaCode. The code also tries to invoke javascript. At that time, the webview is not loaded. 

On clicking the notification message, app will load and so the webview. But at that time, the notification event (which is initiated by JavaCode at the time of receiving notice) will not invoke.

Answer (score 3):

i've found a simple solution.
In the GCMIntentService, just before send javascript check if the webview is loaded :

```
while (GCMPlugin.gwebView == null || GCMPlugin.gwebView.webView == null || !GCMPlugin.gwebView.webView.isEnabled()) {
    // Wait until webView is enabled
}
GCMPlugin.sendJavascript(json);
```

This works for me ... maybe is a good choise to add also a timeout in order to prevent an infinite loop ( it shouldn't happen but ... )

Davide